# Problema de loop para classificar alunos (tranquilo para quem tem um bom conhecimento com python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop

Olá, eu preciso de um programa que receba uma lista de alunos e suas médias, e com base nessas médias diga se ele está abaixo ou acima dela. Essa lista deve conter a inicial de cada aluno e sua média, por exemplo: "J 91", e assim que o registro for inserido, o programa deve informar se o aluno está "Acima da média" ou "Abaixo da média", o programa só pode finalizar quando for digitado especificamente "# 0". Todas as médias iguais ou maiores que 80 estão acima e as iguais ou menores que 79 abaixo.

Tentei resolver algumas vezes e não consegui, agradeço se alguém conseguir me dar uma luz.

```
A, M = input().split()
A = str(A)
M = int(M)

while M != 0:

 if M >= 80:
  print("Acima da média")
 else:
  print("Abaixo da média")
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Basta passar a parte do `split` do `input` também para dentro do `while`:

```
a, m = input().split()
a = str(a)
m = int(m)

while m != 0:
    if m >= 80:
        print("Acima da média")
    else:
        print("Abaixo da média")
    a, m = input().split()
    a = str(a)
    m = int(m)
```